# Can I tell if application has memory leak only based on it's memory consumption?

Tags: asp.net, .net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I was told on one of environments ASP.NET application consumes even up to 64GB of RAM. I don't know how long it takes to consume it and I have not tried to monitor this app with any kind of tool yet. But I suspect that this is some memory leak. My colleague said that maybe it is not and that it's possible that GC decides not to garbage collect because it still has 64GB RAM left.

From what I understand it's not possible to use that much of RAM without some extensive caching built in and I have not seen this in this applications' source code. I know GC can decide to grow Generation 0 when it sees that it needs more space but in order to consume 64GB this memory must be used by either Gen2 or LOH right? This is Business Intelligence app and it does store some data in Session between postbacks so that it does not hit data warehouse every time but still 64GB of RAM consumed seems suspicious to me.